# HTML5 srcset: is 1x mandatory?

Tags: html, srcset

When using a responsive image set with `<img>` without breakpoints (i.e. without the `sizes` attribute) you typically provide several versions of the same image in different resolution which you then define in the `srcset` attribute using the pixel-density syntax, e.g. `1x`, `2x`, `3x`

However, usually the `1x` version of the image is just the same image that is already defined in the `src` attribute, so it's a bit redundant. Thus I am wondering - is defining the `1x` version of an `<img>` in the `srcset` parameter really necessary/mandatory?

When using only

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" srcset="http://placehold.it/700x300 2x">
```

instead of

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" srcset="http://placehold.it/350x150 1x, http://placehold.it/700x300 2x">
```

then at least FireFox will properly display the `350x150` image and as soon as the zoom level/dppx is `> 1` it will use the `700x300` image.

Omitting the 1x definition in the `srcset` would save a few bytes, especially on a page with a large thumbnail gallery for example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#update-the-source-set) says:

> If *child* has a `src` attribute whose value is not the empty string and *source set* does not contain an image source with a density descriptor value of 1, and no image source with a width descriptor, append *child*'s `src` attribute value to *source set*.

Which means you can omit the `1x` source if it’s the same as the `src` attribute, but you can not do that if you are using width descriptors.

Comment: Thank you very much :). Makes sense.